# Adding table border in jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

How do you create a report with table like data?

I was able to create a report with details below.  It arranges the data in a table-like structure.

```
<jasperReport>  
.
.
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <text><![CDATA[ID: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <text><![CDATA[NAME: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <text><![CDATA[AGE: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

But the rows and columns has no border?  How do I achieve this in Jasperreport 4.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- You can add borders with help of GUI designer (*iReport*, for example) or you can add the ***box*** element manually (edit the *jrxml* file) like in this sample:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="29" y="17" width="100" height="20"/>
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

- In *iReport* you can use *"Padding And Borders"* context menu.
  [image: iReport context menu]
- In *Jaspersoft Studio* you can set borders with help of *Properties* dialog (tab *Borders*).

[image]

Comment: hi..@Alex..can we add only right border to particular textField/label from GUI(iReport) ? I can't do this..any idea? Thanks

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia  Yes, of course. You are doing something wrong

Comment: Hi..@Alex Thanks but, I can't get any option in GUI..either I can add border to all side or not any side by option "Padding And Borders" which you mentioned. Can you please help me how?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia You should post your question