# Exporting a Jasper report to odt adds table boundaries lines

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have made a very simple jrxml template which is essentially a picture and 2 fields in the header and a list of data in the detail. I export the report to pdf and odt using java code.  I have just started with this and have done the simplest one as a proof of concept.  So far so good.   When I export to pdf it exports exactly as required and as it looks in jaspersoft studio (6.0.3).  When I export to odt I have grid lines all over the place making it look messy.  These lines aren't in the report and they are obvioulsy table boundaries as I can remove them from the odt file by removing table boundaries. The borders not showing in the report or pdf.

I can't see any border properties for these sections?  Does anyone know if there is a way to set all borders to blank for the odt export?  Has anyone else come across this?

EDIT
I've realised this is only an issue when exporting from Java so maybe this somethign to do with the way I'm doing it.  Apologies for the shocking code, after having taken a few wrong  turns I'm very much doing a proof of concept before doing any proper coding but this is what I'm doing.

I'm guessing now that I need to add something to the SimpleOdtReportConfiguration but I haven't found anything yet?

Anyone encountered this before ?

```
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Templates\\report1.jrxml");

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(),
                new JRTableModelDataSource(tableModel));
       JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Templates\\sample.pdf");

        JROdtExporter exporter = new JROdtExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Templates\\sampleout.odt"));
        SimpleOdtReportConfiguration config = new SimpleOdtReportConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(config);
        exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies should have searched better (this is the reverse of the problem!)

[Adding table border in jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278067/adding-table-border-in-jasperreports)

basically deleted the box elements solved the issue.

Regards (and some relief)

Comment: I've just marked this as the answer as this seems have been viewed quite a few times (I was notified of a popular question badge!) and so may well be helping people to find the real answer!  If you think it should be deleted as noise just leave a comment and I'll do it.